# Let $A = (0,1] \cup \{2\}$ be considered a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Why is $(0,1]$ not closed in $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was reading up about relative metrics and I came across the following statement:
[image: The question]

I don't understand why $(0,1]$ isn't both open and closed. We can write down $B =(0,1]$ as the intersection of $C = [0,1]$ and $A$. Obviously, C is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, so therefore $B = A \cap C$ and thus shouldn't $A$ be closed in $(A,d)$ as well? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time,

K. Kamal.

Comment: Where did they say it isn't closed? As far as I can see, they haven't mentioned whether it's closed at all.

Comment: @Arthur they state that ${2}$ is both open and closed in $A$, so I thought that if $(0,1]$ would be both open and closed, that they would have also mentioned that.

Comment: If they wanted to complete the pattern, yes, they should have. But apparently they didn't.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I agree that the wording is odd. It is always true that if a set $A$ is both open and closed in some metric space (or topological space), then its complement $A^c$ is also both open and closed.